# What is the difference between keyboard-configuration/layout and keyboard-configuration/layoutcode?

Tags: keyboard-layout, preseed, debconf

I am trying to automate the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 Server. While trying to set the keyboard layout to German, I noticed two different configuration options: `keyboard-configuration/layout` and `keyboard-configuration/layoutcode`

What is the difference? Do I need both? Which one can be passed as boot parameter and which has to go into a preseed file?

Where can I find a list with legitimate values? Am I right, that, for a German keyboard layout, I have to set the boot parameters to:

`keyboard-configuration/layout=German` and
`keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=de` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From debconf, each of them is different in some subtle way:

```
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string de
```

Here, `layoutcode` only accepts short strings, like "en", "es", "es-LA", etc. is the equivalent of typing it with the keyboard in the d-i interface.

```
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layout select German
```

Here is the equivalent to the scrollable menu, where all options are in a readable format, like "English (US)" or "English (UK)".

So, difference isn't very noticeable. You can use `layoutcode` if you want to fine select which layout your keyboard is, `layout` is the more user-friendly list where you can just type the full name.